# Problem with opening pen drive

Tags: windows, usb, troubleshooting, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I've a Pen Drive. And I'm not able to format it..
when I'm going for formatting it shows that its formatting but even after half an hour its still formatting...

The PD is not opening. and AntiVirus is showing that no files is present in the PD...

What to do??
Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

Is it new?  The flash memory may be corrupt and that is why it's unable to be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I've had similar symptoms, the drive has never recovered. I believe it may be toast - I hope you had the contents backed up. If it's a new one, take it back and get a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I think the PD memory got corrupted.

- Try to format with NTFS format: Right Click on my Computer >> Manage >> Go to Device Manager >> Under >> Disk Drive >> Locate your Pendrive >> Right click select Properties >> Under the policy tab click on  "Optimize for Performance"
- Try if your able to format with 3rd party softwares like [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-127-hp-usb-disk-storage-format-tool)
- Before you throw away that PD check whether its working in some other computer